# When trying to use clear:both, it does not work

Tags: css

There are quite a lot of questions on this subject, but no answer resolved my problem.

I want that for small screens there is no floating around some image.  So I have

```
@media (max-device-width: 639px), (max-width: 639px) {
div.enimage { display: block; clear:both; }
div.enimage img { max-width: 100%; height: auto; border: 0; display: block; clear:both; }
}
```

for this

```
<div class="enimage">
<a href="pic/img1.jpg"><img align="left" border="0" height="192" width="264" src="pic/img2.jpg" /></a>
</div>
<p>Some text.</p>
```

It does not work, text is still floated right of the image!  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "There are quite a lot of questions on this subject" - I don't see a single question in your post.

Comment: @NullDev Will "What I am doing wrong?" do?

Answer (score 1):

**Don't use the `align` attribute.** It has been deprecated for 20 years now.

Add `float: left` to the image's CSS rules and `float: none` when you want to remove it.

```
div.enimage img { 
  float: left;
}

@media (max-device-width: 639px), (max-width: 639px) {
  div.enimage img { 
    float: none;
  }
}
```

```
<div class="enimage">
  <a href="pic/img1.jpg"><img height="192" width="264" src="pic/img2.jpg"></a>
</div>
<p>Some text.</p>
```

Comment: `float: none` did the trick.  Why?  I thought `clear: both` will do the trick.

Comment: `clear: both` should be applied to the content that should "clear" the floating element, not the floating element itself.

Answer (score -1):

use display: inline-block; instead of display:block;

```
div.enimage {
    display: inline-block;
    clear: both;
}
```